# Palindromic palindrome checker

Tags: code-challenge, palindrome

Write a program to test if a string is palindromic, with the added condition that the program be palindromic itself.

Comment: If the language has till-the-end-of-the-line comments this is trivial so I guess those should be disallowed.

Comment: @Joey I'd happily discourage use of such comments, but disallowing them after posing the question is harsh on those who have already answered. @Ventero's answer (the only one not using them) is way ahead on vote count, so everyone seems to agree.

Comment: Well, to weed out such problems earlier (this also occurred in a similar task on SO) you could use the sandbox or the Puzzle lab ;-)

Comment: How about imposing that the program should be a palindromic quine itself *evil grin* ;-)

Comment: If someone find a way, he instantly wins because of the characters saved.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I think it needs an arbitrary winning criterion, such as popularity contest or code-golf. The question specifies none.

Answer (score 34):

### Ruby

```
z=gets;puts *z.reverse==z&&1||0||1&&z==esrever.z* stup;steg=z
```

Prints 1 if the input is a palindrome, 0 if it isn't. Input without linebreak.

Doesn't use any comments, instead it uses 2 tricks:

- Short-circuiting: `0` is true-ish in Ruby (only `nil` and `false` evaluate to false), so `1&&z==esrever.z* stup` isn't evaluated and thus can't raise a runtime exception
- The splat/multiplication operator (`*`): To avoid a syntax error in `z=esrever.z stup`, we force the parser to parse this as `z=esrever.z()*stup` by adding a `*`. On the other side, the `*` is parsed as a splat operator, which in a function call splits an array in a series of parameters. If there's only one element instead of an array, it basically does nothing, so `puts *foo` is equivalent to `puts foo`.

Obvious solution using comments (prints true/false):

```
puts gets.reverse==$_#_$==esrever.steg stup
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works. I don't know ruby.

Comment: @mellamokb: I added a short explanation. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Answer (score 28):

**Python without comment**

```
"a\";w=]1-::[w trinp;)(tupni_war=w;";w=raw_input();print w[::-1]==w;"\a"
```

I'm surprised that no one found that trick yet, it should work in most languages!

Comment: Very Clever, I like the escaping quote.

Comment: Nice solution, you could even drop the `print` statement and if you allow the input to specified enclosed in quotes `raw_input()` can be shortened to `input()`. Missing an extra '=' at the start.

Comment: removed trailing output after True or False: `"a\"#;w==]1-::[w;)(tupni_war=w;";w=raw_input();w[::-1]==w;#"\a"`

Comment: @Willem Replace `;#` with `!=` and you've got a comment-free solution again, assuming printable input.

Answer (score 14):

### Perl

`perl -nle "$s=$_ eq+reverse;print$s;s$tnirp;esrever+qe _$=s$"`

no comment tricks, just cleverly abusing the substitution operator (hey, perl variables start with a $ too, so what?)

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2.7

```
s=raw_input();print'YNEOS'[s!=s[::-1]::2]#]2::]1-::[s=!s['SOENY'tnirp;)(tupni_war=s
```

Answer (score 6):

### C

```
#include <stdio.h>                   //
#include <string.h>                  //
int main() {                         //
  char str[1024];                    //
  fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);    //
  int i = 0, j = strlen(str) - 2;    //
  for (; i < j; i++, j--)            //
    if (str[i] != str[j]) {          //
      printf("no\n");                //
      return 0;                      //
    }                                //
  printf("yes\n");                   //
}                                    //
//                                    }
//                   ;)"n\sey"(ftnirp  
//                                }    
//                      ;0 nruter      
//                ;)"n\on"(ftnirp      
//          { )]j[rts =! ]i[rts( fi    
//            )--j ,++i ;j < i ;( rof  
//    ;2 - )rts(nelrts = j ,0 = i tni  
//    ;)nidts ,)rts(foezis ,rts(stegf  
//                    ;]4201[rts rahc  
//                         { )(niam tni
//                  >h.gnirts< edulcni#
//                   >h.oidts< edulcni#
```

Running example:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 c.c && ./a.out 
blahalb
yes
```

Comment: won't win for brevity, but I'm impressed

Comment: lol, clever-lvl 11/10.

Answer (score 5):

## Golfscript

```
.-1%=#=%1-.
```

- just with comment trick
- input without \n at the end
- perform matching char by char (even for punctuation)
- returns 1 for success, 0 for failure

Answer (score 4):

## PHP

```
echo strrev($z)==$z;#;z$==)z$(verrts ohce
```

Facts:

- `$z` string, the input string to check
- `$t` boolean, TRUE if the input string `$z` is palindrome, FALSE otherwise
- Using comments to help me make the code palindrome.
- Outputs `$t`
- Source itself is a palindrome

The reason why it will not be possible to implement palindromic palindrome checker in PHP it's because PHP variables are named starting with a `$`. You cannot end an identifier name with `$` in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP

```
<?php eval/*/*/(';{$i=fgets(STDIN,2e9);};{$a="strrev";}{var_dump("{$i}"=="{$a($i)}");}/*}{*\{;("{(tupni$)a$}"=="{putni$}")ohce}{;"verrts"==a$};{;(9e2,NIDTS)stegf=i$);');/*\*\eval php?>
```

Uses some odd tricks to avoid the `$` issue, technically isnt a palindrome as I had to sneak a `;` in at the end.

```
 <?php $i = fgets(STDIN,2e9); echo $i == strrev($i);/*\;(i$)verrts == i$ ohce ;(9e2, NIDTS)stegf = $i php?>
```

This is a working one that uses PHP's `/* */` comments and the fact that you don't need the end for them.

Comment: In the end first code, `eval` should be `lave`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Fuzzy Octo Guacamole](https://github.com/RikerW/Fuzzy-Octo-Guacamole), 17 bytes

```
^Cz.=i_;@;_i=.zC^
```

<sub>Not exactly sure how the win is defined, but I put the byte count up top.</sub>

`^` gets the input and pushes it to the first stack.

`C` copies the first stack to the second.

`z` reverse the top of the stack, so "as" becomes "sa".

`.` shifts the active stack, so the active stack has the input, and the inactive one has the reversed input.

`=` checks for equality, returning `0` for equality.

`i` inverts the ToS, so `0` becomes `1`, and anything else pretty much becomes `False`.

`_` pops and sets the temp variable which the `;` then prints.

`@` ends the program manually, so it doesn't hit the reversed part.  This makes the palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript

I actually struggled with the reverse spellings of 'split', 'reverse' and 'join' :\

```
p=(s)->s.split('').reverse().join('')==s#s==)''(nioj.)(esrever.)''(tilps.s>-)s(=p
```

Answer (score 1):

### Groovy

```
print args[0]==args[0].reverse()?1:0//0:1?)(esrever.]0[sgra==]0[sgra tnirp
```

Comment: You have used comments over here!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 55 bytes

Uses a comment, but is shorter than the other Python one that uses comments.

```
s=input();print(s==s[::-1])#)]1-::[s==s(tnirp;)(tupni=s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript

```
function a(b){return b==b.split('').reverse().join('')}//})''(nioj.)(esrever.)''(tilps.b==b nruter{)b(a noitcnuf
```

Hard to do it without comments...