# Palindromic palindrome generator

Tags: code-golf, string, restricted-source, palindrome

Create a program, that converts input string to a palindrome starting with the input string. The program itself must be a palindrome.

For example input: `neverod`, print `neveroddoreven`. You should handle multi-word, multi-line inputs as well.

Comment: This seems very similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/palindromic-palindrome-checker), except here we're generating instead of checking. Chances are the same tricks will be employed to make the program a palindrome, though.

Comment: I can totally understand the question downvote, but why was the answer downvoted?

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm guessing its because it uses comments to make the palindrome, which specifically makes that strategy ok. It's not a very interesting way and is specifically banned in at least one question requiring palindromic code:http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/28190/15599  . Tomek, welcome to programming puzzles and codegolf. I'm upvoting anyway so you have access to our sandbox http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/15599 however I recommend you stick around and answer a few questions before you ask another one. Also, remember to search for similar questions before posting

Comment: Are functions allowed (instead of whole programs)?

Comment: Can we use a delimiter for the palindrome generated? i.e. `neverod` -> `neverodadoreven` (with the `a` in between)

Comment: This question now has a duplicate: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98325/palindromize-this-string

Comment: Do we have to handle null bytes in input? I have a lang that can, but itd save bytes if i didnt have to

Answer (score 28):

## Dyalog APL, <strike>6</strike> 4

```
⌽,,⌽
```

[Try it here.](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%20%u233D%2C%2C%u233D%20%u22C4%20f%20%27abcde%27&run)

Other solutions:

```
⌽,⊢⊢,⌽
⌽⊢⊢,⊢⊢⌽
```

#### Explanation

They are just:

```
{⌽((,⍵),(⌽⍵))}
{⌽((,⍵)⊢((⊢⍵),(⌽⍵)))}
{(⌽⍵)⊢((⊢⍵),((⊢⍵)⊢(⌽⍵)))}
```

Monadic `,` and `⊢` does nothing on strings. Dyadic `,` is concatenation. Dyadic `⊢` returns its right operand. And `⌽` is obviously reversion.

Comment: Note that this only works in Dyalog APL.

Answer (score 23):

## piet 19x2 = 38

[image: http://www.pietfiddle.net/img/aoNhlwC47U.png?cs=15&rot=4]

Accepts input until it encounters 0x00. Doesn't terminate, but output will be correct.

Comment: Symmetric: yes; palindromic: ?

Comment: @Blue I don't think it's possible to make a PNG image file palindromic due to the header and footer. Also, PNG compression means that the bytes in the image are almost certainly not palindromic.

Comment: @EsolangingFruit Though one could argue that the image equivalent of a palindrome should be centrosymmetric.

Answer (score 19):

### APL, 9

```
⍞←Z,⌽,Z←⍞
```

Explanation:

```
       Z←⍞  ⍝ read a line from the keyboard, and store it in Z
      ,     ⍝ flatten into one-dimensional array (this has no effect here)
     ⌽      ⍝ reverse
   Z,       ⍝ concatenate Z to its reverse
⍞←         ⍝ explicit output (not necessary, but it makes it a palindrome)
```

Answer (score 13):

## CJam, 13 bytes

```
qL;_-1%1-_;Lq

qL;                 "Read the input, Put an empty array on stack and pop that array";
   _-1%             "Now the string is on top, make a copy and reverse the copy";
       1-           "Remove occurrences of integer 1 from the reverse string. [no-op]";
         _;         "Copy the reversed string and pop it";
           Lq       "Put an empty array on stack and read the remaining input. Remaining";
                    "input will be empty as we already read whole of the input";
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qL%3B_-1%251-_%3BLq&input=asdf123)

---

or..

## GolfScript, 9 bytes

```
.-1%}%1-.

.                 "Input is already on stack. Make a copy";
 -1%              "Reverse the copy";
    }             "This marks the beginning of a super comment. Anything after this in the";
                  "code is a comment";
     %1-.         "no-op comment";
```

[Try it here](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJhc2RmZzEyMyIKCgouLTElfSUxLS4%3D)

Comment: I think you've found a bug in the GolfScript parser with your "super-comment". Mind you, an ordinary `#` comment would work just as well there.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Its not me, `}` has been known to be a super comment since ages :)

Answer (score 8):

### C++, 162 bytes

```cpp
#include<cstdio>//
main(){int c=getchar();if(c>0)putchar(c),main(),putchar(c);}//};)c(rahctup,)(niam,)c(rahctup)0>c(fi;)(rahcteg=c tni{)(niam
//>oidtsc<edulcni#
```

### C, 117 bytes

```c
main(c){c=getchar();if(c>0)putchar(c),main(),putchar(c);}//};)c(rahctup,)(niam,)c(rahctup)0>c(fi;)(rahcteg=c{)c(niam
```

Comment: god bless the two slashes lol

Comment: suggest replacing `c>0` with `~c`, also ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘main’ with no type but gcc allows it

Answer (score 8):

## Haskell, 102+22=124 bytes

```
a b fa=fa<|>b
fa=reverse>>=a
main=interact fa
niam=main
af tcaretni=niam
a=>>esrever=af
b>|<af=af b a
```

This must be run with the `Control.Applicative` module in scope, which can be set via the ghci init file `.ghci`: `:m Control.Applicative` (-> +22 bytes).

No comment trick, just 7 functions where 4 of them are never called.

If functions (instead of programs) are allowed:

## Haskell, 55+22=77 bytes

```
a b fa=fa<|>b
f=reverse>>=a
a=>>esrever=f
b>|<af=af b a
```

Usage `f "qwer"`-> `"qwerrewq"`

Edit: the previous version was just wrong.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
+z_z " z_z+
```

In Pyth, anything preceding with a space is not printed. So we simply add the negative of the string to itself, put a space, start a string and mirror the left side of the quote"

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bz_z%20%22%20z_z%2B&input=asdfgh)

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 44

```
s=gets p
s+=s.reverse||esrever.s=+s
p steg=s
```

Takes a multiline string as input from stdin, outputs a Ruby representation of that string concatenated to its reverse. Could trim a character by replacing `||` with `#` to comment out the dead code on the second line.

Comment: `s=gets p`!=`p steg=s`

Comment: ...true, I have no idea what I meant by that.

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 9 bytes

[Try Here](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=Yc63K2lfaSvOt2E)

```
aη+i_i+ηa
```

Explanation: I only just started Jolf and I don't think I'm explaining this properly.

```
aη         alert function, arity of the function can't be reduced by 1 so it stays at 1
  +i_i     concatenate the input with the reversed input
      +η   arity of the add reduced by 1, it just takes the following character (a)
        a  returns the input
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I saw your other answer, and I fondly appreciate you using this language! It is my own inventions, I hope you like it :) This is a really nice solution, very well done! I like the way you used `η` in the solution, very well done. You can save two bytes by eliminating the mu, as: `a+i_i+a`. (Jolf also has implicit input to fill in the rest of the arguments, but this isn't a problem since only one input is given at a time.) I would keep your original solution in the answer, still.

Comment: @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thanks! I just chose a golfing language that didn't seem too scary and jumped in, I've been enjoying figuring it out. I was trying to figure out where the η came from and realized that it was from trying to fix my starting point of +i_i+. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 67

```powershell
$args|%{$_+-join$_[$_.Length..0]}#}]0..htgneL._$[_$nioj-+_${%|sgra$
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFRCoAgDADQw7S@xOFBvIHICBpqxAyV@ijPvt676sOtZz5PVdha6t/6Ahl71CJAAQg9SxoZ0cW5zOgQ80jCHgkCgZR6WEPwrl9PbQNVFb651f0H)

As suggested by @mazzy the code can be shortened by 12 bytes when using a static range. This, however, limits the input length to 9KBytes. Theoratically 9MBytes would be possible but it would slow down the code significantly.

```powershell
$args|%{$_+-join$_[9kb..0]}#}]0..bk9[_$nioj-+_${%|sgra$
```

Comment: Alternative 67 bytes: `param($s)$s+-join$s[$s.Length..0]#]0..htgneL.s$[s$nioj-+s$)s$(marap`

Comment: if input string length less then 9Kbytes then `$args|%{$_+-join$_[9Kb..0]}#}]0..bK9[_$nioj-+_${%|sgra$` (55 bytes)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
êêêê
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=6urq6g==&input=Im5ldmVyb2Qi)

#### How it works

```
U.ê("ê".ê("ê"))  Transpiled to JS

       .ê("ê")   String.ê(string): true if `this` is palindrome
    "ê".ê("ê")   true (treated same as 1)
U.ê(          )  String.ê(number): palindromify
                   "abc"->"abccba" if `number` is odd, "abcba" otherwise
                 `true` is odd number, so we achieve the desired function
```

## Alternative 4 bytes

```
pwwp
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=cHd3cA==&input=Im5ldmVyb2Qi)

#### How it works

```
U.p("w".w("p"))  Transpiled to JS
    "w".w(   )   Reverse of "w" ("p" is ignored)
U.p("w")         Append U.w(), which is reverse of U, to the right of U
```

Answer (score 2):

## Fuzzy Octo Guacamole, 17 bytes

```
^dz''sjX@Xjs''zd^
```

Alt solution in 19 bytes:

```
^Czs''.jX@Xj.''szC^
```

They both take input, duplicate and reverse, and join the stack.

Explanation:

```
^dz''sj@js''zd^
^                # Get input
 d               # Duplicate ToS (input)
  z              # Reverse ToS
   ''            # Push empty string (for joining separator)
     s           # Move the empty string to the inactive stack
      j          # Join the active stack with the top of the inactive stack as the delimiter and push the result.
       X         # Print the ToS
        @        # End the program
        Xjs''zd^  # Backwards version of the beginning.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v), 55 bytes

```
.~""?§0 26 0«0 72!=0_~?(___|___(?~_0=!27 0«0 62 0§?""~.
```

###### Explanation

```
.~""?§0 26 0«0 72!=0_~?(___|___(?~_0=!27 0«0 62 0§?""~.

.                            Input string, push to stack
 ~                           Print top of stack without newline
  ""                         Push empty string to stack
    ?                        Swap top two elements
     §                       Split top of stack (now the user input) with second element of stack (`""`)
      0                      Push 0
        26                   Push 26
           0                 Push 0
            «                Goto ; redirects program to the `|`
                           | Reverses instruction pointer direction, now going left
                          _  Pop stack
                         _   Pop stack (again)
                        _    For the third time, pop the stack
                       )     Decrement top of stack
                      ?      Swap top two elements
                     ~       Print top of stack without newline
                    _        Pop stack
                   0         Push 0
                  =          Execute next instruction only if top two elements of the stack are equal
                 !           Exit, executed only if the top two elements of the stack are equal
               72            Push 27 (pointer is going left, so literal 72 -> value 27
             0               Push 0
            «                Goto _
                          _  (Loop goes on, go back to the first "Pop stack")
                            ___(?~_0=!27 0«0 62 0§?""~. This part is useless and never executed, only for the palindrom requirement
```

What it does is first print the first part of the palindrom, the string itself. Then it stores every letter of the string and the string's length on the stack in reverse order, and print them.

[run online](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#e86c1b42879e59e7696711550bfd6586b97297c9e600e5471d2b5a51644f70fa) (`>` is the prompt, it is not an output of the program)

---

Or, with the string reverse operator :

```
.~—;!;—~.
```

Inputs a string, prints it, reverses it, and prints it.
[run online](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#6c4bd368594074d83cb8b30581d910e40a56301f858a04c84c9f7b1e377a5cb7)

Answer (score 1):

## [tinyBF](http://esolangs.org/wiki/TinyBF), 40

```
|=||==>|=|=|=+|=>==||==>=|+=|=|=|>==||=|
```

My first thought was Brainfuck, but it's impossible to match the braces... fortunately tinyBF has simpler flow control.

No comments, it takes a null terminated string as input and returns the result in a null terminated string.  You can test it [here](http://bataais.com/tinyBF.html), just be forewarned that it doesn't halt (although Firefox at least prompts to stop the unresponsive script).

**Commented:**

```
|=|                        Retrieve a byte of input.
|                          Positive (opening) bracket.
   ==                      Output the byte.
   >                       Move the pointer in positive direction.
   |=|                     Retrieve a byte of input.
   =                       Switch direction to negative.
|                          Negative (closing) bracket.
=                          Switch direction.
+                          Increment byte to execute return loop.
|                          Opening bracket.
   =>                      Move the pointer in negative direction.
   ==                      Output the byte.
|                          Closing bracket.
|=|                        Output the null terminator.
|==>|=|=|=+|=>==|          ...and keep null terminating it just to be sure.
```

Note that if you encode it into 2 bit instructions, it cuts the size to 10 bytes (wouldn't be a palindrome).

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 59 bytes

```
a=input()#
print(a+a[::-1])#([1-::]a+a)tnirp
#()tupni=a
```

I tried my best to find a solution that only used one line but I had no luck.

### Python 3, 79 bytes

```
a=input()#()tupni=a#
print(a+a[::-1])#([1-::]a+a)tnirp
#a=input()#()tupni=a
```

My original attempt in which every line is a palindrome. I don't think that it is necessary for this challenge, but I included it just in case.

Comment: One-line but even longer (73, since `lambda` is so long): `print((lambda a:a+a[::-1])(input()))#)))(tupni()]1-::[a+a:a adbmal((tnirp`

Comment: Very nice. I'm less familiar with lambdas but I'm slowly getting used to them. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy, 9 bytes

```
z:Zr?rZ:z
z          Grab all string input from the command line arguments.
 :         Duplicate this stack.
  Z        Print all elements in this stack as a string.
   r       Reverse (reverses an empty stack).
    ?      Go right a stack.
     r     Reverse (reverses the input).
      Z    Print all elements in this stack as a string.
       :   Duplicate the stack (duplicates an empty stack).
        z  Grab all input from the command line (the command line arguments stack is already empty).
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=ejpacj9yWjp6&input=&args=VGhpcyBpcyBhIHN0cmluZy4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](http://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 37 bytes

```
~:0`!#v_:,
  >:#,_@_,#:>  
,:_v#!`0:~
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=fjowYCEjdl86LAogID46IyxfQF8sIzo-ICAKLDpfdiMhYDA6fg&input=bmV2ZXJvZA)

The top line pushes and prints every character of input. The second line (before the `@`) prints the stack in reverse, but we enter at the contional `_` to consume the -1 generated when finish reading input. The other half of the code (including those ugly trailing newlines) makes the source a palindrome, but nevers runs.

Answer (score 1):

## C# (<s>33</s> 32 + 1) * 2 = <s>68</s> 66 bytes

saved 2 bytes to the use of .Aggregate()

```cs
s=>s+s.Aggregate("",(a,b)=>b+a);//;)a+b>=)b,a(,""(etagerggA.s+s>=s
```

Oh the good old lambda, you can catch it with

```cs
Func<string, string> f=<lambda here>
```

and then call it with

```cs
f("neverod")
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 45 bytes

```pl
;print$_=<>,~~reverse;m;esrever~~,><=_$tnirp;
```

Pretty straightforward, `print`s the input (`$_=<>`) followed by the `reverse` of it. `reverse` returns `$_` because we're using it in scalar context by prefixing with `~~`. Then we match (`m//` using `;` as delimiter), in void context, against the reverse of the script.

If we can guarrantee we won't have to create a palindrome of `esrever,><=_$tnirp` we can shorten the code to **43 bytes**:

```pl
g.print$_=<>,reverse.m.esrever,><=_$tnirp.g
```

#### Usage

```sh
echo -n 'neverod' | perl -e 'g.print$_=<>,reverse.m.esrever,><=_$tnirp.g'
neveroddoreven
```

---

### Perl, 26 bytes

**Includes 25 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```pl
$_.=reverse;m;esrever=._$
```

I don't think this is valid since it requires the `-p` flag which I don't think can be easily combined into the script contents to make a true palindrome. Pretty much the same calls as above, except it relies on the fact that `-p` also adds a `;` behind the scenes (on newer Perls...) to close the `m//`.

#### Usage

```sh
echo -n 'neverod' | perl -pe ';$_.=reverse;m;esrever=._$;'
neveroddoreven
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>5</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
R«R
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/6NDqoP//lZSUSjIyi7mAKJGrJLW4BCgAAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
R        # Reverse the (implicit) input
         #  i.e. "neverod" → "doreven"
 «       # Append it to the (implicit) input
         #  → "neveroddoreven"
  R      # Reverse it (no-op, since it's a palindrome)
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

If we are allowed to output `neverodoreven` for the input `neverod`, which is still a palindrome, it can be done in **1 byte** instead with the palindromize builtin:

```python
û
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8O7//5WUlEoyMou5gCiRqyS1uAQoAAA)

Comment: I think `R«R` works. Reversing a palindrome doesn't do much

Comment: @ovs Ah, of course. Smart thinking, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
m
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJtIiwiIiwiYmFnIl0=)

A simple 1-byter - `m` mirrors input by appending its reverse.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>5</s> 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
x+x
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/79Cu@L/f6W81LLUovwUJS6lpJxEIGloZGxiamZuYakEAA)

Or 1 byte if overlapping the last character would be allowed, with the palindromize builtin:

```
ñ
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///wxv//lfJSy1KL8lOUuJSSchKBpKGRsYmpmbmFpRIA)

**Explanation:**

```python
x    # Reverse the (implicit) input
 +   # Append it to the (implicit) input
  x  # Reverse it (no-op, since it's a palindrome)
     # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 15

```
 k k+ z_z +k k
```

Notice the space at the beginning and at the end.

Quite annoying task in Pyth. `z_z` prints the desired palindrome, but it prints `z` (the input string) and `_z` the inverse on two different lines. `+` combines the two words, but `+` at the end requires two new statements at the end (and at the beginning). I choose `k` and `k`, which are just empty strings. Then a lot of white space, which suppresses printing (and printing empty spaces, which generate of course line breaks).

Since the white space suppresses every output except the `+z_z`, you can replace the `k`s and literal with arity 0. E.g. `1 2+ z_z +2 1` or `T Z+ z_z +Z T`.

Try it [online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%20k%20k%2B%20z_z%20%2Bk%20k%20&input=neverod&debug=0).

Comment: I have an 11 one in Pyth, which I did not post yet coz I thought you will surely beat it ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 138 bytes

I'm not using the "comment trick" but I am using the escaped quotation mark trick lol.

```
"a\"};))''(nioj.)(esrever.)''(tilps.b(tacnoc.b nruter{)b(a noitcnuf;";function a(b){return b.concat(b.split('').reverse().join(''));};"\a"
```

Comment: I don't think this counts; the two central chars are `";`. Adding a `;` as the last char inside the string should fix this.

Comment: As it stands this answer is invalid. Please either fix it or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 58 bytes

```
p=>p+[...p].reverse().join``//``nioj.)(esrever.]p...[+p>=p
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 28+1+28=57 bytes

```
<?=($x=$argv[1]).strrev($x);#;)x$(verrts.)]1[vgra$=x$(=?<
```

takes input from command line argument. quote for multi-word, escape newlines for multi-line.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 51 bytes

```
s=input();print s+s[::-1]#]1-::[s+s tnirp;)(tupni=s
```

I'm surprised no-one thought of this! Needs quoted input (`'` or `"`). If functions were allowed, I could have done this for 37 bytes instead:

```
lambda x:x+x[::-1]#]1-::[x+x:x adbmal
```

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, <s>152</s> 116 bytes

As unnamed lambda, assumes `s` to be `string`

```c++
[](auto s){decltype(s)r;for(auto c:s){r=c+r;}return s+r;}//};r+s nruter};r+c=r{)s:c otua(rof;r)s(epytlced{)s otua(][
```

Old solution:

```c++
[](auto s){auto r=s;for(auto p=s.rbegin()-1;++p!=s.rend();r+=*p);return r;}//};r nruter;)p*=+r;)(dner.s=!p++;1-)(nigebr.s=p otua(rof;s=r otua{)s otua(][
```

Usage:

```c++
auto f=[](auto s){decltype(s)r;for(auto c:s){r=c+r;}return s+r;};

main(){
 string a="123456789";
 cout << f(a) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## x86-64 Assembly (Microsoft x64 calling convention), 89 bytes:

```
80 39 00 48 8B D1 4C 8B C1 74 0B 48 FF C2 49 FF C0 80 3A 00 75 F5 48 FF CA 8A 02 41 88 00 48 8B C2 48 FF CA 49 FF C0 48 3B C1 77 ED C3 ED 77 C1 3B 48 C0 FF 49 CA FF 48 C2 8B 48 00 88 41 02 8A CA FF 48 F5 75 00 3A 80 C0 FF 49 C2 FF 48 0B 74 C1 8B 4C D1 8B 48 00 39 80
```

Disassembled:

```
 0000000000000000: 80 39 00           cmp         byte ptr [rcx],0
 0000000000000003: 48 8B D1           mov         rdx,rcx
 0000000000000006: 4C 8B C1           mov         r8,rcx
 0000000000000009: 74 0B              je          0000000000000016
 000000000000000B: 48 FF C2           inc         rdx
 000000000000000E: 49 FF C0           inc         r8
 0000000000000011: 80 3A 00           cmp         byte ptr [rdx],0
 0000000000000014: 75 F5              jne         000000000000000B
 0000000000000016: 48 FF CA           dec         rdx
 0000000000000019: 8A 02              mov         al,byte ptr [rdx]
 000000000000001B: 41 88 00           mov         byte ptr [r8],al
 000000000000001E: 48 8B C2           mov         rax,rdx
 0000000000000021: 48 FF CA           dec         rdx
 0000000000000024: 49 FF C0           inc         r8
 0000000000000027: 48 3B C1           cmp         rax,rcx
 000000000000002A: 77 ED              ja          0000000000000019
 000000000000002C: C3                 ret
 000000000000002D: ED                 in          eax,dx
 000000000000002E: 77 C1              ja          FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF1
 0000000000000030: 3B 48 C0           cmp         ecx,dword ptr [rax-40h]
 0000000000000033: FF 49 CA           dec         dword ptr [rcx-36h]
 0000000000000036: FF 48 C2           dec         dword ptr [rax-3Eh]
 0000000000000039: 8B 48 00           mov         ecx,dword ptr [rax]
 000000000000003C: 88 41 02           mov         byte ptr [rcx+2],al
 000000000000003F: 8A CA              mov         cl,dl
 0000000000000041: FF 48 F5           dec         dword ptr [rax-0Bh]
 0000000000000044: 75 00              jne         0000000000000046
 0000000000000046: 3A 80 C0 FF 49 C2  cmp         al,byte ptr [rax+FFFFFFFFC249FFC0h]
 000000000000004C: FF 48 0B           dec         dword ptr [rax+0Bh]
 000000000000004F: 74 C1              je          0000000000000012
 0000000000000051: 8B 4C D1 8B        mov         ecx,dword ptr [rcx+rdx*8-75h]
 0000000000000055: 48 00 39           add         byte ptr [rcx],dil
 0000000000000058: 80
```

Note that the code after the `ret` instruction at `2C` is unreachable so it doesn't matter that it's nonsense

Answer (score 0):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), <s>33</s> 27 bytes

```
iH~0}|{<:: oi]io ::<{|}0~Hi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/z/To86gtqbaxspKIT8zNjNfwcrKprqm1qDOI/P//8SkZAA)

Unlike a lot of the solutions here, this one actually *does* use the palindromised code!

#### Explanation:

```
i  0 |{      Get the first character and enter the loop
        :  o    Output the character while preserving it
              i  :     Get input and duplicate it
                   <{  Turn around
             ]         Increment the copy to check if EOF   
    }| <    Loop again if not EOF
  ~   If EOF, pop the extra copy of EOF
 H    Terminate, printing the contents of the stack.
```

Altogether, the unexecuted instructions are:

```
       :   i  o :   |}0~Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) + coreutils, <sup><s>33</s></sup> 23 bytes

```sh
tee >(rev) # )ver(> eet
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/JDVVwU6jKLVMU0FZQbMstUjDTiE1teT//4xMAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
t=input();print(t+t[::-1])#)]1-::[t+t(tnirp;)(tupni=t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcgxDoAgDAXQw7i0MQzErYSTEHa7fBvyGTx99Y0vXt4Prkx2R2yKtlgOCk8Os1KnHjprMRv/COErmgp3wDszPw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
+ Q_Q +
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X1shMD5QQfv/f6W81LLUovwUJQA)

Uses implicit variables at the end of the program, which was not a feature when the other Pyth answers here were posted.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
º
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0K7///NSy1KL8lMA) For multiline input, surround the input in triple quotes (`"""`).

```
º  # full program
º  # push...
   # implicit input...
º  # concatenated with...
   # implicit input...
º  # reversed
   # implicit output
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work for all characters that will be mirrored (e.g. `/<{([`).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>(26+1)*2=54</s> (19+1)*2=40 bytes

```kotlin
    var palindrome:(String)->String=
```

```kotlin
    {s->s+s.reversed()}//})(desrever.s+s>-gnirtS:s{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsIwEEX3PUXoagZJuxfMJTxBIKMGp0mZiXURcvYYdOFfPf7j/2cuHFM/vJjdDwqSNzrDtUhMd7TuB5de1To96SJ0kCgFwLauDSGQfqtlSGe19tsrmc3HBFgnM7KPfeEE/3eYH8SczTsLhxlxav0D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Headascii](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass#Headascii), 63 bytes

```
{N)UPO}:+E.N-)++E:{UN)RO}:RPNE.!.ENPR:}OR)NU{:E++)-N.E+:}OPU)N{
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@thejonymyster/HA23) Code will have to be copied and executed like this:

```js
erun("{N)UPO}:+E.N-)++E:{UN)RO}:RPNE.!.ENPR:}OR)NU{:E++)-N.E+:}OPU)N{","your input")
```

This was rough. You can't have mismatched curly braces in headass/ascii in code blocks that are accessed, even if the braces are never reached, so I couldn't do anything clever with reusing backwards code.

Explanation:

```
{N)UPO}:+E.N-)++E:{UN)RO}:RPNE.!.ENPR:}OR)NU{:E++)-N.E+:}OPU)N{

{N)UPO}:+E.  Block 0

{     }      Loop, which
 N)    :     While there is still unread input,
   UP        Reads input and concatenates it to the string register
     O       And pushes the input to the "output" array.
        +E   Go to block 1, pop the entire output array,
              and push it onto the input array
          .  Block separator
    

N-)++E:{UN)RO}:RPNE.  Block 1

N-)                   If there is nothing left in the input array
   ++E                  Go to block 2
      :               Else
       {     }          Loop, which
        U               Reads and discards an input byte
         N)             If there's still more input,
           RO             Recall the discarded byte and
                           save it to the output array
              :         Else, exit the loop, and
               R          Recall the discarded byte and
                P         concatenate it to the string register
                 NE     Return to the start of block 1,
                         pop the entire output array,
                         and push it onto the input array
                   .    Block separator

!.  Block 2

!   Print the string register
 .  Block separator, end execution


ENPR:}OR)NU{:E++)-N.E+:}OPU)N{  Blocks 3 and 4

     }     {           }     {  Tragic mismatched curly braces
                                 which prevent me from reusing
                                 reversed code. These blocks
                                 are invalid and inaccessible
```

Copies the string, repeatedly concatenates the last character of the copy to the original and removes it from the copy, until the copy is gone.

I think block 1 is golfable, but im out of ideas for now. This is pretty much just the canonical solution, without much actual golfing other than `A()`=>`A)` and `[+` => `N` type stuff, small optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```scala
s=>s+s.reverse//esrever.s+s>=s
```

Just the "comment trick", I was not able to provide a shorter solution without it :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctNCsIwEIbhfU8xdNUitPizEhLwBoIniMlEIjEJM6EWimePtYuCdPfyzDeslVcl3p@oM1yVd8FQfDm9JgKOGYNhuKQEUwUwKA/2DLdMLjxAyLUKC8k77ggHJMa@R16ym1EKLgBpHmYfGtvU4XeJpm7b6s83sD8cTxu0kd6Klu9P@QI)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 56 bytes

```javascript
f=([c,...d])=>c?c+f(d)+c:''//'':c+)d(f+c?c>=)]d...,c[(=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcoxDoMwDIXhvadALLEVGgR0qJBCD4IYgh0jGChKUa6fwoYY3/f@xUX3ozBv@zO@UxILPRXGGB7QdvQhLcCoqVWqLJVqSSOD6OPoLA58hAX1YCVl2RbmdQeBfPXRhy/niI@L3mZVN68buZHYy3Rq@gM)

Why no one recurse?

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 100 bytes

```c
main(c){read(0,&c,1)&&putchar(c,main(write(1)));}//};)))1(etirw(niam,c(rahctup&&)1,c&,0(daer{)c(niam
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoQwDAXQ24QEItq1pwm/YeyiVUIdF@LZO4O7Bw/TBxijWmkMucMt86IETUJ0nB2bBUPfv6J05yQi6zPPz/pHYu8lLm7FqoLDNvTzIJKkIF04m8cteH@M5l@PPf8A)