# Palindromize this string!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, palindrome

Your task is to palindromize a string as follows:

Take the string.

```
abcde
```

Reverse it.

```
edcba
```

Remove the first letter.

```
dcba
```

Glue it onto the original string.

```
abcdedcba
```

But here's the catch: since this challenge is about palindromes, **your code itself also has to be a palindrome.**

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the smallest number of bytes wins.

Comment: There should be a hefty bonus for any code that does not use comments to fulfill the palindrome requirement.

Comment: @Theo Then it would go straight to the golf-langs with the palindrome builtin. I don't really see the need for it, and doing it without a comment is more of a personal challenge.

Comment: @miles Fair enough. Although I would love to see some creativity from the non-golfing-langs in general.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/77095/20260).

Comment: @miles It´s virtually impossible for non-eso-langs to do this without a comment. You can´t just palindromize predefined function names. Maybe it can be done, but it would ridiculously blow up the size.

Comment: Can there be an exception for the program to substitute exact characters for mirrored characters in its palindrome? I.e. Allowing "(1+1)" as a palindrome. I think it would increase the competitiveness of non-golf languages.

Comment: Actually, it´s not an exact duplicate. You have to remove one character from the input here.

Answer (score 17):

## Python 3, 41 bytes

```
lambda t:t+t[-2::-1]#]1-::2-[t+t:t adbmal
```

[Try it here](https://goo.gl/6W6SZX).

Comment: My first Python answer

Comment: Not that it matters, but one of your reversed brackets is the wrong direction.

Comment: @xnor Thank you! Corrected

Comment: I think he means the other one

Answer (score 16):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
û
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w7s&input=YWJjZGU)

Comment: Yep. One char is a palindrome.

Comment: how do you have a built in for this

Comment: @undergroundmonorail: It is quite often useful in ascii art challenges, or really any challenge with horizontal symmetry.

Comment: @Emigna I guess that's fair. I thought "I wonder what function is being horribly abused because it happens to generate this output" but no, I checked the docs and sure enough it's called "palindromize" haha

Answer (score 15):

## Dip, 1 byte

```
B
```

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 13.</sup>

Answer (score 14):

## Pyth - 13 bytes

It kinda looks like its crying.

```
+Qt_Q " Q_tQ+
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQt_Q+%22+Q_tQ%2B&input=%22abcde%22&debug=0).

Comment: +1 for almost being `Q_Q`

Comment: Hate to see a `Qt` crying

Comment: You can use `z` instead of `Q` to not need quotes in the input (Which I think you need to add 2 bytes for the required chars in input (http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2Bzt_z+%22+z_tz%2B&input=abcde&debug=0)

Comment: @Artyer actually, I don't need to add 2 bytes for the `"` because it is such a common and standard input format. I could have used `z`, but I was expecting to use the implicit input feature of `Q`, but ended up not using it, and didn't go back and change it.

Answer (score 11):

## [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), <s>149</s> 137 bytes (47 chars + 2 newlines)

```
붛뱐쎤붇쎡뻐처순의이멓희
빠본땨벌다따토먀의썩속썩의먀토따다벌땨본빠
희멓이의순처뻐쎡붇쎤뱐붛
```

Due to the nature of the Aheui language, the input must end in a double quotation mark (") (gets ignored).

[Try it here! (copy and paste the code)](http://jinoh.3owl.com/aheui/jsaheui_en.html)

**Bonus (each line is palindromic)**, 131 bytes (42 chars + 5 newlines)

```
밯빪반분반빪밯
쏜발뚝볃뚝발쏜
쏙툼닿뗘닿툼쏙
뽓첡순괆순첡뽓
숙쌱멈긕멈쌱숙
몋희익욥익희몋
```

Answer (score 4):

## APL -- 13 bytes.

```
⊣,¯1↓⌽⍝⌽↓1¯,⊣
```

Explanation:

```
⊣,¯1↓⌽
     ⌽ Reverse the argument.
  ¯1↓  Drop the last character.
⊣,     Concatenate the original to the result.
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>86</s> bytes

```
s=>s+[...s].reverse().slice(1).join("")//)""(nioj.)1(ecils.)(esrever.]s...[+s>=s
```

I tried a smarter solution but it's still longer :/ even abusing `[,...a]=s` didn't seem to save bytes

Comment: aww you ninja'd me

Comment: You can use `join\`\`` instead of `join("")`

Answer (score 3):

## J, 17 bytes

```
}:,|.NB. .BN.|,:}
```

Takes the easy way out by using a comment to mirror the code. In J, `NB.` starts a line comment. I do hope to find a method that doesn't involve a comment but the digrams in J probably do make it harder.

Also forms two smileys, `}:` and `:}`.

### Usage

```
   f =: }:,|.NB. .BN.|,:}
   f 'abcde'
abcdedcba
```

### Explanation

Comment part removed since it is just filler.

```
}:,|.  Input: string S
   |.  Reverse S
}:     Curtail, get S with its last char removed
  ,    Join them and return
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, (<s>51</s> 50 + 1)*2 = <s>104</s> 102 bytes

saved 2 bytes to the use of `.Aggregate()`

```cs
s=>s+s.Aggregate("",(a,b)=>b+a,s=>s.Substring(1));//;))1(gnirtsbuS.s>=s,a+b>=)b,a(,""(etagerggA.s+s>=s
```

You can capture this lambda with

```cs
Func<string,string> f = <lambda here>
```

and call it like this

```cs
f("abcde")
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 47 bytes

```
->s{s+s.reverse[1..-1]}#}[1-..1]esrever.s+s{s>-
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
f=#~Join~Rest@Reverse@#//Function;noitcnuF//#@esreveR@tseR~nioJ~#=f
```

Defines a named function `f` that takes a list of characters as input and returns the appropriate palindromized list as output. The bit after the semicolon (is fortunately syntactically valid and) gives a second, way more complicated name to this same function.

It was fun trying to make Mathematica make sense without any brackets!

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 11 bytes

```
:Lc.r
r.cL:
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OkxjLnIKci5jTDo&input=InRlc3Qi&args=Wg)

#### Explanation

```
:Lc.         Input concatenated with a string L results in the Output
   .r(.)     The Output reversed is still the Output
```

The second line is a new predicate declaration that never gets called in that code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
RiXßRkΣkRßXiR
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=UmlYw59Sa86ja1LDn1hpUg&input=ImFiY2RlIg)

**Explanation**

```
R          # reverse input
 i         # flatten
  X        # discard top of stack
   ßR      # push reversed input
     kΣ    # concatenate each
k          # wrap in list
 R         # reverse
  ß        # push input
   X       # discard it
    i      # flatten list to string
     R     # reverse string
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 1 bytes

```
s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=s&input=test)

Yes, this is the same builtin as the digital root one. This time it takes a sting and turns it into a palindrome. Added with [this commit](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/commit/7e79dc95866b451ded61a07cb1da79cf1b1009fb) (actually on the same day as the digital root question)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 38+39=77 bytes

```
<?=($s=$argv[1]).substr(strrev($s),1);#;)1,)s$(verrts(rtsbus.)]1[vgra$=s$(=?<
```

stupid restriction ... for non-eso languages :)

Comment: your 3rd character is an `=`, but does not come back in the end

Comment: @nl-x Typo ... the bytecount was correct ... apart from the missing `$` for `argv`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## WinDbg, <s>142</s> 287 bytes

```
db$t0 L1;.for(r$t1=@$t0;@$p;r$t1=@$t1+1){db$t1 L1};r$t3=@$t1-1;.for(r$t1=@$t1-3;@$t1>=@$t0;r$t1=@$t1-1;r$t3=@$t3+1){m$t1 L1 $t3};eb$t3 0;da$t0;*;0t$ad;0 3t$be;}3t$ 1L 1t$m{)1+3t$@=3t$r;1-1t$@=1t$r;0t$@=>1t$@;3-1t$@=1t$r(rof.;1-1t$@=3t$r;}1L 1t$bd{)1+1t$@=1t$r;p$@;0t$@=1t$r(rof.;1L 0t$bd
```

*+145 bytes to make it a palindrome, nearly missed that requirement...*

Input is passed in via an address in psuedo-register `$t0`. For example:

```
eza 2000000 "abcde"           * Write string "abcde" into memory at 0x02000000
r $t0 = 33554432              * Set $t0 = 0x02000000
* Edit: Something got messed up in my WinDB session, of course r $t0 = 2000000 should work
* not that crazy 33554432.
```

This may be more golfable, for example I feel like there should be an easier way to convert a memory address in a register to the value at that address.

It works by concatenating the chars from the second-to-last to the first to the end of the string.

```
db $t0 L1;                                      * Set $p = memory-at($t0)
.for (r $t1 = @$t0; @$p; r $t1 = @$t1 + 1)      * Set $t1 = $t0 and increment until $p == 0
{
    db $t1 L1                                   * Set $p = memory-at($t1)
};
r $t3 = @$t1 - 1;                               * Point $t3 at end of string

* From the second-to-last char, reverse through the string with $t1 back to the start ($t0)
* and continue to increment $t3 as chars are appended to the string.
.for (r $t1 = @$t1 - 3; @$t1 >= @$t0; r $t1 = @$t1 - 1; r $t3 = @$t3 + 1)
{
    m $t1 L1 $t3                                * Copy char at $t1 to end of string ($t3)
};
eb $t3 0;                                       * Null terminate the new string
da $t0;                                         * Print the palindrome string

* Comment of the previous code in reverse, making the whole thing a palindrome
*;0t$ad;0 3t$be;}3t$ 1L 1t$m{)1+3t$@=3t$r;1-1t$@=1t$r;0t$@=>1t$@;3-1t$@=1t$r(rof.;1-1t$@=3t$r;}1L 1t$bd{)1+1t$@=1t$r;p$@;0t$@=1t$r(rof.;1L 0t$bd
```

Output:

```
0:000> eza 2000000 "abcde"
0:000> r $t0 = 33554432
0:000> db$t0 L1;.for(r$t1=@$t0;@$p;r$t1=@$t1+1){db$t1 L1};r$t3=@$t1-1;.for(r$t1=@$t1-3;@$t1>=@$t0;r$t1=@$t1-1;r$t3=@$t3+1){m$t1 L1 $t3};eb$t3 0;da$t0;*;0t$ad;0 3t$be;}3t$ 1L 1t$m{)1+3t$@=3t$r;1-1t$@=1t$r;0t$@=>1t$@;3-1t$@=1t$r(rof.;1-1t$@=3t$r;}1L 1t$bd{)1+1t$@=1t$r;p$@;0t$@=1t$r(rof.;1L 0t$bd
02000000  61                                               a
02000000  61                                               a
02000001  62                                               b
02000002  63                                               c
02000003  64                                               d
02000004  65                                               e
02000005  00                                               .
02000000  "abcdedcba"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 146 bytes

(Enter is added for readibility and not part of the code.)

```
String c(String s){return s+new StringBuffer(s).reverse().substring(1);}/
/};)1(gnirtsbus.)(esrever.)s(reffuBgnirtS wen+s nruter{)s gnirtS(c gnirtS
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 152 bytes

```java
String c(char[]s,int i){return s.length==i+1?s[i]+"":s[i]+c(s,++i)+s[i-1];}//};]1-i[s+)i++,s(c+]i[s:""+]i[s?1+i==htgnel.s nruter{)i tni,s][rahc(c gnirtS
```

Comment: [Beat ya to it with a shorter answer few seconds before you.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/98411/52210) I like the manual recursive approach instead of `new StringBuffer(s).reverse()` though. Unfortunately I don't see anything to make it shorter this time. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen you won.Actually i am weak with handling strings.I need to open my java book.

Comment: Seems like this makes it even `String c(char[]s,int i){return s.length<i+2?s[i]+"":s[i]+c(s,i+1)+s[i];}`

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```haskell
p s=init s++reverse s--s esrever++s tini=s p
```

[Try it on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/VOY2MY) Saved 2 bytes thanks to Damien.

Straight forward solution. `init` takes everything but the last character of a string (or last element of a list). `--` enables a single line comment.

Comment: `init s++reverse s` is shorter

Answer (score 1):

## R, 107 bytes

This is the boring solution which just uses comments to make it a palindrome.

```
cat(x<-scan(,""),rev(strsplit(x,"")[[1]])[-1],sep="")#)""=pes,]1-[)]]1[[)"",x(tilpsrts(ver,)"",(nacs-<x(tac
```

## R with few comments, 271 bytes

While this code is longer, only 89 of the bytes (33%) are comments, rather than the 50% in the above code. R relies extensively on parentheses for function application, so this was rather difficult.

```
`%q%`=function
(x,y)cat(x,y,sep=e)#
`%p%`=function
(x,y)`if`(length(y),rev(y)[-1],x)#
x=strsplit(scan(,e<-""),e)[[1]]#
n=NULL
e%q%x%p%n
n%p%x%q%e
LLUN=n
#]]1[[)e,)""-<e,(nacs(tilpsrts=x
#)x,]1-[)y(ver,)y(htgnel(`fi`)y,x(
noitcnuf=`%p%`
#)e=pes,y,x(tac)y,x(
noitcnuf=`%q%`
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 44 bytes

43 bytes, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `-e`

```
s#(.*).#$&.reverse$1#e#1$esrever.&$#.)*.(#s
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 162 bytes

```c
f(char*c,char*d){char*e=c;while(*d++=*c++);c-=2;d-=2;do{*d++=*c--;}while(e<=c);}//};)c=<e(elihw};--c*=++d*{od;2=-d;2=-c;)++c*=++d*(elihw;c=e*rahc{)d*rahc,c*rahc(f
```

Ungolfed, unpalindromized:

```c
f(char* c,char* d){
 char*e=c;
 while(*d++=*c++);
 c-=2;d-=2;
 do{*d++=*c--;}while(e<=c);
}
```

`c` is is input string, assumes output string `d` has sufficient length.

Usage:

```c
int main() {
 char a[] = "abcde";
 char* b=malloc(strlen(a)*2);
 f(a,b);
 printf("%s\n",b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## , 16 chars / 20 bytes

```
ï+ïĦ⬮Đ1//1Đ⬮Ħï+ï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (ES6 browsers only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=asdf&code=%C3%AF%2B%C3%AF%C4%A6%E2%AC%AE%C4%901%2F%2F1%C4%90%E2%AC%AE%C4%A6%C3%AF%2B%C3%AF)</kbd>

Generated from the interpreter console using this:

```
c.value=`ï+ï${alias(String.prototype,'reverse')}⬮${alias(String.prototype,'slice')}1//1${alias(String.prototype,'slice')}⬮${alias(String.prototype,'reverse')}ï+ï`
```