# Pali-n-drome this List

Tags: code-golf

The challenge here is to extend an implementation of palindrome given the following as inputs:

- `n > 1` and a list `l`.

Your program must palindrome the list both vertically and horizontally, that is to say it must first palindrome the list itself, then each element in the list after; or the other way around. Before palindromization, all elements are ensured to be equal length. The palindrome action is then to be performed `n` times in sequence until the desired output is met. The easiest way to show the expected outputs is just to run through a few examples:

---

One iteration performed on `[123,456,789]`:

First you palindromize the list to `[123,456,789,456,123]`.

- While this is not a palindrome if joined together, it is a palindrome in terms of the list.
- `[a,b,c]` became `[a,b,c,b,a]`, so the LIST was palindromized.

Then, you palindromize each list element `[12321,45654,78987,45654,12321]`.

This is how each iteration is performed, it's essentially an omnidirectional palindrome.

---

Given `n=1 and l=[123,456,789]`:

```
12321
45654
78987
45654
12321
```

Given `n=2 and l=[123,456,789]`

```
123212321
456545654
789878987
456545654
123212321
456545654
789878987
456545654
123212321
```

Given `n=1 and l=[3,2,1]`:

```
3
2
1
2
3
```

Given `n=2 and l=["hat","mad"," a "]`:

```
hatahatah
madamadam
 a a a a 
madamadam
hatahatah
madamadam
 a a a a 
madamadam
hatahatah
```

Given `n=2 and l=[" 3  ","2000"," 100"]`:

```
 3   3 3   3 
2000002000002
100 00100 001
2000002000002
 3   3 3   3 
2000002000002
100 00100 001
2000002000002
 3   3 3   3
```

Given `n=4 and l=["3 ","20","1 "]`:

```
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
20202020202020202
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
20202020202020202
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

Given `n=3 and l=["_|__","__|_","___|"]`:

```
_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___|_
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
___|_____|_____|_____|___
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___|_
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
___|_____|_____|_____|___
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___|_
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
___|_____|_____|_____|___
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___|_
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
___|_____|_____|_____|___
__|_|___|_|___|_|___|_|__
_|___|_|___|_|___|_|___|_
```

Given `n=2 and l=["---|---","__|","___|","____|"]`:

```
---|-----|-----|-----|---
  __|   |__   __|   |__  
 ___|   |___ ___|   |___ 
 ____| |____ ____| |____ 
 ___|   |___ ___|   |___ 
  __|   |__   __|   |__  
---|-----|-----|-----|---
  __|   |__   __|   |__  
 ___|   |___ ___|   |___ 
 ____| |____ ____| |____ 
 ___|   |___ ___|   |___ 
  __|   |__   __|   |__  
---|-----|-----|-----|---
```

## Rules

- `n` will always be greater than 1.
- `l` will always have more than 1 element.
- All elements of `l` are the same length.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) shortest solution will be marked as winner.

Comment: This would be a better challenge if we didn't have to pad elements.

Comment: @JonathanAllan it's an omnidirectional palindrome, or 2D palindrome you could say. I've updated the description; also, the padding prevents a few odd fringe cases where a smaller string is already a palindrome.

Comment: @JonathanAllan it is in terms of the list, if you are looking at the LIST as the item to be palindromized. Just like [@1,@2,@1] is also a palindrome when looking at it as a list, not by the elements...

Comment: @JonathanAllan yeah, essentially, you can look at it like that if you want.

Comment: @mbomb007 changes made, fair enough.

Comment: Last example requires padding.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47827/34718)

Comment: Is it n>1 or n>0?

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Note that if only a single iteration was required (`n=1`), then the program would be the palindrome `û€û`.

```
Fû€û
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@92ePejpjWHd/@vPbT7vxFXtJKCsYKCko6SkYGBAZBSMARSsQA)

```
F       Do n times
 û      Palindromize the list
  €û    Palindromize each element in the list
```

---

If padding the input was still a required part of the program (11 bytes):

```
€R.B€RIFû€û
```

I couldn't find a shorter way to right-justify. Left-justification and centering were all easy, but this was longer for some reason. Using `E` or `²` instead of `I` also works.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>71</s> 63 bytes

```python
lambda x,n,f=lambda x:x+x[-2::-1]:eval('f(map(f,'*n+`x`+'))'*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bYrLbsMgEEX3/YoRm4F4kAxO@kDKlziIUKVOkWJqRW7lhf/dHZN6V4mZO5xzr8fTcov9@yXCRJm64/ZxUzW12jqnjXcfP/EmsZN9HGRHuMvVeTpXqBSfaum@7pAgZX7D9yiVe4LhnvIIifCUka5yl9TSti0a2yDh/vDM@@X1DT0ZT/9yW/hKLY/ZmuIzjoJEHy@8IYL4awpoABjZuq5XYzg21TwEL7P29wWGOQQmgbNEmFk1RWmtZ56H3WSJUrLeL78)

Assign a palindrome function to `f`, generate and evaluate the following pattern (for `n=4`)
`f(map(f,f(map(f,f(map(f,f(map(f,<input>))))))))`

Comment: I think you mean *assign*. I don't think *assing* is a verb, lol.

Comment: @mbomb007 welp, time to get more coffee~

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒḄŒB$¡
```

Dyadic link, or full program taking the list and `n`.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@3900sMdLUcnOakcWvj/cHvk///RSrq6ujVArKSjpKAQH1@joABlAZkgVjyEFfvfCAA)**

Using both versions of Lynn's fantastic built-in "bounce".

```
ŒḄŒB$¡ - Main link: l, n
     ¡ - repeat n times
    $  -     last two links as a monad (firstly with l then the result...)
ŒḄ     -         bounce ("palindromise") the list
  ŒB   -         bounce the elements
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
h=lambda a:a+a[-2::-1]
f=lambda a,n:n and f(h(map(h,a)),n-1)or a
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PYzBCoMwEETP9SuWnBK6e9DjQr9EJGwxIYJZRXr039MtFQ8zPIaZaeW1Sn3PAsLylJEGZuqnLt8xKiuIzpB98VV2X1BCQKU@bAdIy@ZpTTXpBxa11uiI6DQ5dAAxngAXGf4o/mlCGAJ3j/1YbHpdtC8)** - footer prints each of the elements of the resulting list, one per line, a "pretty print".

`h` is the palindomisation function, it appends to the input, all the elements of a list from the last but one, index -2, to the start in steps of size -1.

`f` calls `h` with the result of calling `h` on each element in turn, reduces `n` by one and calls itself until `n` reaches 0, at which point `a` is the finished product.

Comment: ...and I am still forgetting the `f=` for recursive functions, one day I'll remember.

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 15 bytes

```
(Z¨Z←⊢,1↓⌽)⍣⎕⊢⎕
```

Explanation:

- `(`...`)⍣⎕⊢⎕`: read the list and `N` as input, and run `N` times:

  - `⊢,1↓⌽`: the list, followed by the tail of the reversed list
  - `Z←`: store this function in `Z`
  - `Z¨`: and apply it to each element of the list as well

Test:

```
          (Z¨Z←⊢,1↓⌽)⍣⎕⊢⎕ 
    ⎕:
          'hat' 'mad' ' a '
    ⎕:
          2
    ┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
    │hatahatah│madamadam│ a a a a │madamadam│hatahatah│madamadam│ a a a a │madamadam│hatahatah│
    └─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 66 bytes

```
{x,n->f={z->z+z[z.size()-2..0]};n.times{x=f(x).collect{f(it)}};x}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 51 bytes

```
x%n=iterate((++)<*>reverse.init)x!!n
x?n=(%n)<$>x%n
```

Usage example: `["123","456","789"] ? 1` -> 
`["12321","45654","78987","45654","12321"]`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@1@hmmebWZJalFiSqqGhra1po2VXlFqWWlScqpeZl1miWaGomMdVYZ9nq6Gap2mjYgdU/z83MTNPwVYhN7HAV6GgtCS4pMgnT0FFIVrJWEFJR8nIAEgYKijFKtgrmPwHAA).

`(++)<*>reverse.init` makes a palindrome out of a list, `iterate(...)x` repeats this again and again and collects the intermediate results in a list, `!!n` picks the nth element of this list. `(%n)<$>x%n` makes a n-palindrom of each element of the n-palindrome of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```
f=(n,l,r=l=>[...a].reverse().slice(1))=>n--?f(l.concat(r(l)).map(s=>s+r(s).join``),n):l
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 25 bytes

24 bytes of code, +1 for `-l` flag.

```
Lq{gM:_.@>RV_gAL:@>RVg}g
```

Takes the list as command-line arguments and the number *n* from stdin. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@@9TWJ3uaxWv52AXFBaf7uhjBWKk16b//2/0Xzfnv6GR8X8TU7P/5haWAA)

#### Explanation

```
                          g is list of cmdline args (implicit)
Lq{                   }   Read a line of input and loop that many times:
      _.@>RV_             Lambda function: take all but the first character (@>) of the
                           reverse (RV) of the argument (_), and concatenate that (.) to
                           the argument (_)
   gM:                    Map this function to g and assign the result back to g
                 @>RVg    Take all but the first element of the reverse of g
             gAL:         Append that list to g and assign the result back to g
                       g  After the loop, print g (each item on its own line due to -l)
```